# RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number - when creating SparkSession using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, config

I'm experiencing issues with creating a SparkSession, namely I get "RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number" error.

Here's the snippet I use:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .master('local[1]') \
                    .appName('recommendation_engine') \
                    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', './clickhouse-native-jdbc-shaded-2.6.5.jar') \
                    .getOrCreate()
```

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong or missing something?

Thanks!

I have already checked if all possible and imaginary environmental variables are in place - YES(SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, PYTHONPATH etc.)

I have tried and run this part before creating SparkSession:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--jars ./clickhouse-native-jdbc-shaded-2.6.5.jar"
os.environ['PYSPARK_ALLOW_INSECURE_GATEWAY'] = "1"
```

I have checked various articles but none of them gives an idea of a checklist I have to follow to resolve this problem.

Comment: Where does `$JAVA_HOME` point to? Do you have Java installed on your machine?

Comment: SOLVED: Ok, so after running 'set JAVA_HOME = <path to JAVA_HOME>' in a command line prompt it worked. Still wondering why pyspark behaved this way since I already had an environmental variable set and the path I used in a command line prompt was exactly the same.

Comment: Nice! Maybe you can answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted? This helps future readers in quickly finding the solution to their problem :)

Comment: Good idea. Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Ok, so after running 'set JAVA_HOME = ' in a command line prompt it worked. Still wondering why pyspark behaved this way since I already had an environmental variable set and the path I used in a command line prompt was exactly the same.